# I can't send data from my indexed database

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I lose the reference of the "value" variable when it is no longer in the "onsuccess" context. I don't know how to make this function asymmetric.

```js
    getList(){

        let transaction = this.db.transaction([this.db_name], "readwrite");
        
        transaction.oncomplete= _ => {
            console.log("Success")
        }
        
        transaction.onerror = _ => {
            console.log("Error")
        }
        
        let value = []
        let objectStore = transaction.objectStore(this.db_name)
        
        objectStore.getAll().onsuccess = e => {
            value = e.target.result;            
        };

        console.log(value)
        
        return value

    }
```

When I console.log(value) I get an empty array.

If I wanted to take this data and put it directly in my HTML it would have worked and these are the only examples I managed to find on the internet

Comment: I assume onsuccess is not synchronous. Is getAll() a promise?

Comment: no it return nothing

Comment: If it returns nothing: You can't attach a .onsuccess event listener onto nothing. It would be like writing: `undefined.onsuccess = e => console.log(e)`

Comment: But there must be some way I can get the value of e.taget.result in another function or context..Don't you believe?  `objectStore.getAll().onsuccess = e =>` work very well

Comment: What is this.db ?

Comment: That's the reference of the database that's work. I just don't know how get the value of the onsuccess context. Just it

Comment: Knowing what database/library you are using will probably help to solve the issue.

Comment: it's IndexedDB (browser database) you don't know? I appreciate your help if you still want help me I pass you my whole code. I use IndexedDB MDN tutorial

Comment: You must go and learn about async javascript before proceeding. Your problem is due to your misunderstanding of async javascript.